# Drupal 8/9 Compilation Install Error

Tags: error, installation, css, install, composer

I'm getting thiis error, when I try to install civicrm on Drupal 8 and 9

The following packages have new compilation tasks:

- civicrm/composer-compile-lib has 1 task
- civicrm/civicrm-core has 1 task

Allow these packages to compile? ([y]es, [a]lways, [n]o, [l]ist, [h]elp) y
Compiling additional files (For full details, use verbose "-v" mode.)
Compile: Generate CCL wrapper functions
Compile: Greenwich CSS (dist/bootstrap3.css)

> @php -r 'require_once '''/home/bvivaccinate/public_html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL::copy('''../../bower_components/select2/select2-bootstrap.css''', '''extern/select2/select2-bootstrap.scss''');'
> @php -r 'require_once '''/home/bvivaccinate/public_html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::scss($GLOBALS["COMPOSER_COMPILE_TASK"]);'
> Script @php -r 'require_once '''/home/bvivaccinate/public_html/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::scss($GLOBALS["COMPOSER_COMPILE_TASK"]);' handling the shell-runner event returned with error code 255
> Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 255

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[RuntimeException]
Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 255

These are the commands I ran to install it for drupal 9

php composer.phar create-project drupal/recommended-project

php composer.phar require pear/validate_finance_creditcard:dev-master

php composer.phar config extra.enable-patching true

php composer.phar require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:'~1.1'

php composer.phar require    civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.37.2'

Composer version 2.0.13
PHP 7.3.28

Can someone please assist

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime until this is fixed you can install this patch: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/pull/1.patch

Then run `composer compile`.

May also need to then run `composer civicrm:publish`.

Comment: Newbie question, but how would you apply the patch?

Comment: If you have git and curl on the server, you can do `cd /path/to/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib && curl -L -O https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/pull/1.patch && git apply 1.patch`.

Comment: But the meat of it is just change line 17 in vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/ src/ScssCompiler.php to `public function findImport($url, $currentDir = NULL) {` and line 45 to `return parent::findImport($url, $currentDir);` https://github.com/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/pull/1/files#diff-de1563b44a5c7c9235d6634fd05f7cf80a4696f131122a7b0bf7b00d18e393d0

Comment: Looks like the fix was just merged so you could just try again without patching.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was greatly appreciated